# How to create a reference to a Ruby method so it can be executed later?

Tags: ruby, methods, reference

I would like to do the following in Ruby:

1. Create a class with a method in it
   1.5 Create an instance of the class
2. Create a reference to the method in the instance
3. Execute the method later

Something like this:

```
class Cat
  def meow
    puts "meow"
  end
end

my_cat = Cat.new
portable_meow = my_cat.method("meow")
portable_meow.execute
# outputs "meow"
```

Comment: `portable_meow.execute` is wrong, which would have been reported as an error. Make sure to include details about the *actual* problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `execute`, which does not exist, use `call`.

```
portable_meow.call
```

Answer (score 0):

Both of these solutions work. Thanks everyone for your prompt replies.
(Sorry, I really can't figure out how to get my code to format correctly below, but you get the idea.)
- Matt

```
class Catz
  def meow
    "meow"
  end
end

my_cat = Catz.new
test = my_cat.method(:meow)
puts test.call

my_cat2 = Catz.new
test = my_cat2.method("meow")
puts test.call
```